# Calling view constructor with a parameter

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have a WPF project, with the MVVM pattern.

In code behind, I call a view:

```
NavigateToViewCommand command = new NavigateToViewCommand(Container.Container.GetA<IProductViewModel>());
command.Execute();
```

The NavigateToViewCommand looks like this:

```
public class NavigateToViewCommand : WpfCommand
{
    private readonly object _viewToNavigate;

    public NavigateToViewCommand(object viewToNavigate) : base("Navigate")
    {
        _viewToNavigate = viewToNavigate;
    }

    protected override void RunCommand(object parameter)
    {
        Container.Container.GetA<IMainViewModel>().NavigateToView(_viewToNavigate);
    }

    protected override IEnumerable<string> GetPreconditions(object parameter)
    {
        yield break;
    }
}
```

Here's the IProductViewModel interface:

```
public interface IProductViewModel : IViewModelBase
{
    string Name { get; }
    IEnumerable<string> Products { get; }
}
```

The IViewModelBase is empty interface which implements the INotifyPropertyChanged interface. IMainViewModel implements the IViewModelBase interface.

In my view, I have a constructor without parameters, and constructor with parameter int. I want to call the constructor with the parameter. How do I do that?

Here is my WPFCommand class:

```
public abstract class WpfCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly string _verb;

    protected WpfCommand(string verb)
    {
        _verb = verb;
    }

    public string Verb
    {
        get { return _verb; }
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        RunCommand(parameter);
    }

    protected abstract void RunCommand(object parameter);
    protected abstract IEnumerable<string> GetPreconditions(object parameter);

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return GetPreconditions(parameter).Count() < 1;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: In your first code snippet you get an instance of IProductViewModel, which is presumably the view-model you want to navigate to. Do you want to call the overloaded constructor (`int`) of this IProductViewModel instance?

Comment: @AndrewStephens Yes, IProductViewModel is the view model I want to use for my needed view. I want to call the overloaded constructor of the ProductView, not the view model.

Comment: Your code shows how you get an instance of the VM, but how is its associated view instantiated? I notice in your command code you call the NavigateToView() method of IMainViewModel. Is it in there?

Comment: @AndrewStephens The NavigateToView method is in the MainViewModel class, which extends the ViewModelBase class and implements the IMainViewModel interface.

Comment: @AndrewStephens Here's how I implement it: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/72724/Beginning-a-WPF-MVVM-application-Navigating-betwee

Answer (score 0):

Looking at that CodeProject article mentioned in the above comments, you seem to be using a VM-first approach: you use an IoC container to get instances of your VMs, but the views are data templates. When you navigate to a particular VM, the WPF framework uses the relevant datat emplate (and therefore view) for VM type, so it's unlikely that you could hook into the view's creation process. Even if you could, passing the `int` to the ctr is probably unwise, especially in a dependency injection environment.

Instead, you could expose the `int` as a property on your VM, then access the value in your view's code-behind like this:-

```
// Assumes the int property is called ProductId
var productId = (DataContext as IProductViewModel).ProductId;
```

You'll probably find you can't do this in the view's constructor as the DataContext doesn't get assigned until after the ctr has been called.